# Obtain Data Points (x,y) from a 2D region plot generated from an inequality

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, regions, inequalities

I have a code that generates a region plot modeling an aperture. I would like to generate a table of ordered pairs (x,y) for a given u that manipulates my inequality. When I attempt to great a table all I get is true-false for each point. Is there a way to pull the data points that make up the region plot in the form of a table?

```
Manipulate[
RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - u^2/10^2*x^2*y^2 <= 100), {x, -10, 
10}, {y, -10, 10}], {u, .1, .99999}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pts = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[{x, y}, {x, -10, 10, 0.5}, {y, -10, 10, 0.5}];
Manipulate[   
 \[ScriptCapitalR] = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 - (u^2/10^2) x^2*y^2 <= 100 /. u -> k, {x, y}];
 (*Echo[\[ScriptCapitalR]];*)
 ptsinreg = 
  Pick[pts, ! RegionDisjoint[\[ScriptCapitalR], Point[#]] & /@ pts];
 (*Echo[ptsinreg];*)
 p1 = ListPlot[ptsinreg, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1];
 p2 = RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^2 - (u^2/10^2)*x^2*y^2 <= 100), {x, -10, 
    10}, {y, -10, 10}];
 Show[p1, p2],
 {u, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}
 ]
```

You can remove the comments from `Echo` statements to see your points. Also, you can generate `pts` with the resolution you want.

[image]

Comment: This is great and works perfectly for the model I am trying to build! thank you so much for your help.

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks for the accept and sorry about the late reply.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html).

For example:

```
f[x_, y_, u_] := x^2 + y^2 - u^2/10^2*x^2*y^2;
man[u_, t_, n_, d_] :=
 Module[{grid = Tuples[Range[-n, n, d], 2], pts},
  pts = Point[
    Reap[Sow[{##}, f[##, u] <= t] & @@@ grid, True][[2, 1]]];
  RegionPlot[f[x, y, u] <= t, {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}, Epilog -> pts]]
```

Then,

```
Manipulate[man[u, 100, 10, 1], {u, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

Unfortunately, rendering `RegionPlot` clunky...I am sure this can be smoothed.
(posted just to illustrate `Reap` and `Sow`).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

SeedRandom[1234];

rgn3 = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 - u^2/10^2*x^2*y^2 <= 
    100, {{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {u, 0.1, 0.99999}}];
```

For random {x, y, u} points that are in the region `rgn3`

```
TableForm[
 pts3 = RandomPoint[rgn3, 10],
 TableHeadings -> {None, HoldForm /@ {x, y, u}},
 TableAlignments -> "."]
```

[image]

Verifying that the points are in the region

```
And @@ (RegionMember[rgn3] /@ pts3)

(* True *)
```

For random `{x, y}` points for a given `u`

```
rgn2 = With[{u = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.99999}]}, 
  rgn2 = ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 - u^2/10^2*x^2*y^2 <= 100, {{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}}];
  Column@{
    StringForm["u = ``", NumberForm[u, {6, 3}]],
    TableForm[
     pts2 = RandomPoint[rgn2, 10],
     TableHeadings -> {None, HoldForm /@ {x, y, u}},
     TableAlignments -> "."],
    And @@ (RegionMember[rgn2] /@ pts2)}]
```

[image]